# Salesforce to Salesforce Connection

Tags: metadata-api

Is there a way , we can fetch all the metadata from one org to another (just the Api name) , so that we can use it to display on the field.

**** Edit ****
So in our agile process , we will include all the API names of the components added/updated in a custom object for a user story. So basically we are manually entering the Api name of the updated/new component. I am wondering if we can connect to any our lower (QA/uat) environments and fetch the metadata and display them in a field , so it will be easy for the user to select from a picklist , instead of adding it manually.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SFSE. In its current form, its not very clear as what you are trying to ask, and thus this question most likely will get closed. Take a moment to go through [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and then if you can [**edit**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/236667/edit) the question to provide more details, someone should be able to help you then.

Comment: You can certainly authenticate to other environments and talk to the Metadata API, using, e.g., the popular `apex-mdapi` library. It won't be trivial, though, and your life will be a lot easier if you use one of the many existing high-quality tools for managing metadata.

Comment: Thanks @DavidReed for the quick response. So what tools do you mean when you are saying high quality tools ? like the eclipse , Mavenmate...  TIA

Comment: example tool: Gearset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand upon my comment, yes, you can, but it's probably more engineering than it's worth and it opens up potential security hazards.

If you're in Salesforce org A and you want to get a list of, for example, field API names in Salesforce org B, you have to do three things:

1. Authenticate to Salesforce org B as a privileged user, one who can access the Metadata or Tooling APIs;
2. Make an API call over one of the two APIs mentioned to source data;
3. Digest the results into usable information to present on the front end for your users.

These are all more or less "solved problems". You can use a Named Credential to authenticate to your other orgs. There's an open source [Apex wrapper](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) for the Metadata API. And so on.

But when you're done putting all of that together just to populate a picklist, you've still got a manual metadata management app running on-platform. I personally would push hard to use any one of the metadata and release management solutions half-a-dozen Salesforce vendors would like to sell you, or - if you have the internal capacity and expertise - building your own backed by version control and some type of CI/CD process.